# WebLogic 12c not obeying "prefer-web-inf-classes" or "prefer-application-packages" during deployment

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am having a very strange problem with WebLogic 12.1.3.0.0. I have an application that causes a `NullPointerException` inside the `AdminServer` during deployment, yet the application runs fine after the error.

The `NullPointerException` during deployment happens because the deployment process is not respecting the following settings in my deployment descriptors:

`AppName.war/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app>

  <context-root>AppName</context-root>
  <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

And `AppName.ear/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application>

    <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

</weblogic-application>
```

Since these settings are ignored, `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` class is loaded by the System Classloader (`sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`), from `$WL_HOME/wlserver/modules/glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar`, not from the WAR classloader. This eventually leads to the `NPE` due to some poorly written code in `weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor`, which assumes that `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` will be annotated with `@MultipartConfig`, which it is not in `glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar`. The correct version of this class is located in `AppName.ear/AppName.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api-2.2.16.jar`.

I have verified all of this by remote debugging the AdminServer, and by turning on Classloader Logging, which shows this:

```
GCL[61ba0535][AppName.ear@AppName.war] GCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[10d372cb][] FCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[10d372cb][] FCL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
GCL[75bc8d74][DomainLib] GCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
```

This issue makes it impossible to open the `AppName` Deployment in the Admin Console, b/c it always throw the error (with the aforementioned NPE in the logs):

```
The configuration for AppName is still being loaded from your last request, please wait a moment and retry.
```

In contrast to this, when I run the EAR in the server where it was deployed, exactly the same EAR works just fine. To prove that classloading is working properly, here's the log:

```
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] CACL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] GCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[37ee3b94][AppName@AppName] FCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[37ee3b94][AppName@AppName] FCL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
GCL[3cc63f62][AppName@] GCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[770e8d03][] FCL.loadClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[770e8d03][] FCL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
FCL[770e8d03][] FCL.matchesClassFilterList(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): javax.faces. index : 0 end : 12>
FCL[770e8d03][] FCL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): Found match>
GCL[3cc63f62][AppName@] GCL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
GCL[3cc63f62][AppName@] GCL.findLocalClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): Classpath in use: <LIST OF ALL JARS IN MY EAR>
GCL[3cc63f62][AppName@] GCL.findLocalClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): not found>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] CACL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] CACL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): About to loadClass>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] GCL.findClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] GCL.findLocalClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): Classpath in use: <LIST OF ALL JARS IN MY WAR>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] GCL.findLocalClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet): Found class>
CACL[6eb4b4ad][AppName@AppName] GCL.defineClass(javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet)>
```

I don't know how to fix this... Why is the AdminServer completely ignoring the deployment descriptors in my EAR, while the server that runs the EAR sets everything up properly?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set prefer-web-inf-classes to true in weblogic.xml you must not set prefer-application-packages in weblogic-application.xml. Choose only one, not both.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin You are correct. I have removed prefer-web-inf-classes from weblogic.xml, but this made no difference at all. The Deploy behavior is unchanged, b/c 'prefer-application-packages' is still being ignored by the AdminServer. It doesn't even create a FilteringClassLoader with my 'classPatterns' in it...